# Printing 2D-Arrays side-by-side in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, stdio

The following are my functions:

```
void initialize(char box[NROW][NCOL]){
    int x,y;
    for(x=0; x<NROW; x++)
        for(y=0; y<NCOL; y++)
            if (x==0 || x==NROW-1 || y==0 || y==NCOL-1)
                box [x][y] = '=';
            else{
                 box[x][y]=' ';
            }

}

void display(char box[NROW][NCOL]){

    int x,y;
    for(x=0; x<NROW; x++){
    for(y=0; y<NCOL; y++){
       printf(" %c ", box[x][y]);
    }
        printf("\n");
    }
}    

void puzp1(char puz1[NROW][NCOL]){

    int x,y;

    for(x=1; x<NROW-1; x++){
    for(y=1; y<=x; y++){
        puz1[x][y]='*';
    }
    }

}

void puzp2(char puz2[NROW][NCOL]){

    int b,c;
    for(b=1; b<NROW; b++){
        for(c=1; c<NROW-b; c++){
            if(b!=3 && c!=3 ){
                puz2[b][c]='+';
                }
                }
            }
}
```

The following is my main:

```
int main(void){

    char ar1[NROW][NCOL];
    char ar2[NROW][NCOL];

    printf("Puzzle Piece 1:\n");
    initialize(ar1);
    puzp1(ar1);
    display(ar1);


    printf("Puzzle Piece 2:\n");
    initialize(ar2);
    puzp2(ar2);
    display(ar2);
```

I realize that there is another thread with a similar question but it does not quite satisfy what I need. What's happening here is that `initialize` generates a hollow rectangle, `puzp1` and `puzp2` decides the content and `display` prints the content.

Is it possible for me to print these two 2D arrays side-by-side; if possible, how?

NROW and NCOL are constants.

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you want to play around with terminal cursor positioning, you will need a function called `display2` or something like that, that prints out two 2D arrays side by side. It shouldn't be too hard if the arrays have the same number of rows. Otherwise, the code will need to output blanks for the missing rows of the shorter array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the 2D arrays are the same size, then for each row, you just need to print the row from the first box, followed by some separating text, followed by the row from the second box.

```
void display2(char box1[NROW][NCOL], char box2[NROW][NCOL]){
    int x,y;

    for(x=0; x<NROW; x++){
        for(y=0; y<NCOL; y++){
           printf(" %c ", box1[x][y]);
        }
        printf("   ");
        for(y=0; y<NCOL; y++){
           printf(" %c ", box2[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```